# Issue in reversing a string with return value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse the string with return value as reversed string and input arguments as input string.
Here is my code:

```
char* reverseString(char* string)
{
    static int i = 0;
    static char *revStr = new char[strlen(string)+1];
    if (*string)
    {
        reverseString(string + 1);
         revStr[i++] = *string;
    }
    return revStr;
}
int main(void)
{
    char* str = "Test it";
    cout << reverseString(str) << endl;;
}
```

output:

```
ti tseT═²²²²
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I tried this in visual studio 2013.I was expecting output to be:

`ti tseT
Press any key to continue . . .`

But i am not getting a correct output, there are some unwanted characters getting added after "tseT". Can anyone suggest me on this? I don't want to change the function argument and return syntax.

Comment: Please explain why you are not using `std::string`?  If this is an assignment with restrictions you should include them in the question so we can give appropriate answers.

Comment: with string class or c++11 i can easily do it, but my intention is not so. I just want to correct my function body.

Comment: You missed to put a raw c-string end indicator `'\0'` at the end. There are probably many more duplicates of that question.

Comment: can you suggest how to modify my code to place '\0' will see if it works.

Comment: @A.Gupta Just put `revStr[i] = '\0';` before the `return` statement.

Comment: @A.Gupta Also note that you can simply use the [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) algorithm to achieve what you want. You don't need to use `std::string` to do that actually.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Yes that worked fine, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Beyond failing to terminate the string properly, this has a serious problem if you call it more than once. For example, something like: `std::cout << reverseString("abc"); std::cout<<reverseString("abcdef");` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I already mentioned my intention is not to use any string class method or any normal function. Just wanted a recursive way with returning reversed string.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I will take care of that .. Thanks

Comment: @A.Gupta That's all fine. I just wanted you make aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the final `'\0'`.

Try adding an `else` statement:

```
if (*string)
{
     revStr[i++] = *string;
    reverseString(string + 1);
}
else
    revStr[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same unwanted characters at the end of  "tseT"

Comment: Make the recursive call after setting `revStr[i++]`. Check edit.

Comment: We do not need "else", just we need "revStr[i] = '\0';" before returning string.